# yolov8 export for tensorflow environment with out ultralytics

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deployment, pytorch, yolov8

I am using ultralytics version 8.0.20 5o train yolov8 model.
I am done training and testing and I want to export my mode to use it on my server.
in my server there is no ultralytics package I only have pytorch and tensorflow installed.
when I use this line from office official document I get this outcome

```
!yolo export model={HOME}/runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt format=saved_model  imgsz= 1024  # export custom trained model
```

```
2023-05-27 16:49:11.934911: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-05-27 16:49:12.893349: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.20  Python-3.10.11 torch-2.0.1+cu118 CUDA:0 (Tesla T4, 15102MiB)
Model summary (fused): 168 layers, 11125971 parameters, 0 gradients, 28.4 GFLOPs

PyTorch: starting from /content/runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt with output shape (1, 5, 21504) (21.5 MB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/yolo", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(entrypoint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/yolo/cfg/__init__.py", line 249, in entrypoint
    getattr(model, mode)(verbose=True, **overrides)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/model.py", line 182, in export
    exporter(model=self.model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/exporter.py", line 213, in __call__
    raise NotImplementedError('YOLOv8 TensorFlow export support is still under development. '
NotImplementedError: YOLOv8 TensorFlow export support is still under development. Please consider contributing to the effort if you have TF expertise. Thank you!
```

It looks like there is not export feature for now.
Is there any way that I could save my model as tf, keras or pytorch model and load them (only for inference) latter with out ultralytics pack.

thank you in advance